# state_activated pre honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout

How do you use

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

for list view items in an apps that should also run on devices <11 ?

Since `activated_state`  is not available before HC, I can only think of two dirty workarounds:

1. Maintain the activated_state manually in your `Activity`.
2. Maintain the activated element in my custom `ListAdapter`

But either one is satisfying. (`getListView().setChoiceMode(...)` wouldn't have an effect,...)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you had a look to this tutorial ?

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-list-indicators-on-honeycomb/

Comment: It does not work for pre-honeycomb, see step 4 from your link

Comment: the issue has been addressed there since :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531272/state-activated-on-pre-honeycomb-devices?noredirect=1&lq=1