# Android listview selector not working in 2.2

Tags: android, list, selector

The list selection is not working in 2.2. I found many of them having this issue but i did not find a solution which is working.

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_activated="false">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_activated="false" android:state_pressed="false">
             <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                 <solid android:color="@color/list_selector" />
            </shape>
        </item>
         <item android:state_selected="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                 <solid android:color="@color/list_selector" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_activated="true">
             <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                 <solid android:color="@color/list_selector" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </selector>
```

The above selector is my listselector. Its working fine in other devices 3.1, 4.1 etc..But its not working in 2.2

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in `android:state_activated` 
It was added in API 11(3.0), so it wont work in prior versions. More info in [doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_activated)

I believe you can accomplish the same behavior using `state_checked` property (available since API 1).

Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531272/state-activated-on-pre-honeycomb-devices).

Hope it helps.